# Bootstrap collapse responsive navbar closes back after opening it when on small screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

The navbar works fine on the big screen but when you go to a mobile screen the collapse closes back after pressing the collapse icon.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #7e9094;">
  <nav style="background-color: #213239;" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand  active" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-target="#demo" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav" id="demo">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="shop/shop.html">Shop</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="projects/projects.html">Projects</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="navbar-text"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><img style="float: right;" width="10%" src="img/image.img"></a></span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js` ie. version `3.4.1`?

Comment: thanks for helping, I guess I'm blind, didn't see it was the old version. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just update the CDN link for your JavaScript to match the CSS. Both need to be on the 4.x version.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #7e9094;">
  <nav style="background-color: #213239;" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand  active" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-target="#demo" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav" id="demo">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="shop/shop.html">Shop</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="projects/projects.html">Projects</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="navbar-text"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><img style="float: right;" width="10%" src="img/image.img"></a></span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1) I consider the issue being just a typo and therefore voted to close it 2) all you did was basically turning my comment into an answer 3) OP is using `4.5.3` which you turned to `4.5.2`. Does that enlight you?

Comment: That was a bold (and arrogant) assumption. I had a snippet built before your comment appeared. Also, version 4.5.3 doesn't exist in the CDNs I looked at.

Comment: Apparently my definition of "typo" differs from yours.

Comment: Apparently yes. Is it likely that this question (and therefore your answer) will help someone else? I don't think so. Which is why I consider it to be a typo or a blind copy-paste from another code snippet. And if you look at the official Bootstrap docs, the current version is 4.5.3.

Comment: It takes time for CDNs to catch up to Bootstrap's releases. Over and out.

Answer (score 0):

it is just a supplement to the answer of @isherwood and @MrUpsidown.

Indeed, you have incompatible css, jquery and bootstrap versions in your code.

If you want to use the latest version of Bootstrap, you should do like in an example from the answer above. It means you need the same version of css as the version of bootstrap is, 4.3.1. It is also recommended to use jquery slim build. You could read more on the ['Getting started' guide for Bootstrap 4.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/).

If you actually need the bootstrap 3.4.1 (that actually was a typo in your code, I believe), you need different css and jquery for it as it follows from the ['Getting started' guide for Bootstrap 3.4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/) An example of navbar for that version of bootstrap you can find [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar).

In this case your code will be something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #7e9094;">
    <nav style="background-color: #213239;" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText"
                aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-target="#demo" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="navbar-nav" id="demo">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="shop/shop.html">Shop</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="projects/projects.html">Projects</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="navbar-text">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><img style="float: right;" width="10%" src="img/image.img"></a>

            </span>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

But be careful. 3.4.1 and 4.3.1 are actually different versions :) Good luck with that!